# Working with different date fields. How to approach towards an easier search engine? Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I built a small site where I gather information of some cultural events happening in the area. I want to extend the `Event` model so it can handle 3 different 'case scenario' of events.

1. 'i.e. Single'. Normal event with start date and finish date.
2. 'i.e. Band on tour'. Same event but happening at different times.
3. 'i.e. Museum'. Monday to Sunday timetable.

I thought that the best approach for the 1 and 2 types will be:

Event model

```
 # holds title, description, price....
has_many :dates
accepts_nested_attributes_for :dates
```

Date model

```
 # holds start_time(:datetime) and finish_time(:datetime)
belongs_to :events
```

I am not sure how to approach the 3rd type. Or what is more important, how to build it in a way that makes future interactions easier to code... like building a SEARCH engine.

Idea:
Building another model called `Timetable`? 
This could hold:

```
boolean types -> Mon - Tue... -Sun
time type -> Mon_start - Tue_start... - Sun_start - Mon_finish - Tue_finsih... - Sun_finish.
```

However, this seems pretty complicated to update the `search engine`(which has a date field/parameter) to iterate through all these 3 types.

Any ideas/experience which may clarify the path to take? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way that would work well would be to make `Date` abstract, and then make three more models that extend `Date`.

Comment: I have never used. Well, I had a look at them and I am not quite sure. Mainly, because the 3 types of possible Event do not hold the same type of amount of dates. Am I far from what you meant?